# Android play video intent with start position

Tags: android, video

I can play video using intent using the following (thanks to existing answers/questions here):

```
Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```

This plays the video from the top using some default video player.  The question is if it's possible to setup the intent such that video starts playing some seconds (or frames) into the video?

Comment: A little background - if we could start video from a given index, we could then easily show only the interesting parts of an video, say from Youtube, referenced in a message or blog.  It'd even better if we could also specify when it should end (after the funny part, for example).  The best would be a playlist of various segments - this could apply to music too, even as a way of quoting various parts of a blog without showing the whole long boring piece :)

Answer (score 2):

> The question is if it's possible to setup the intent such that video starts playing some seconds (or frames) into the video?

There is nothing in the `ACTION_VIEW` specification that supports this, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Any backdoors? :)

Comment: @Bill: Even if there were, they would be on a per-app basis. If you need this level of control over the video playback, handle the video playback yourself within your own app (e.g., `VideoView`), rather than pass control to third party apps.